ROS2 running on a docker container in WSL cannot communicate to remote machines
This is my setup:

Machine 1: windows running WSL2 running docker container with ROS2 program.
Machine 2: ubuntu machine running docker container with ROS2 program.

I have ping from one machine to another and vice versa.

Configurations I set:

docker flag net=host
ROS_DOMAIN_ID=1 in both
I disabled ufw in both machines


I cannot get the topics I create in one machine appear on the other.
running this simple test case:
ros2 topic pub  /chatter std_msgs/String "data: Hello from WSL" 

When I run
ros2 topic list

on the other machine its not there.
What am I missing?
I saw something online related to Hyper-V configuration but assuming I have ping between them it should be alright.
